# React-native run-ios stuck on building and Xcode crashes immediately when opening workspace file

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Sorry in advance if this is not the appropriate place for this particular question but after 2 days of unsuccessful debugging, I’m hoping to get a fresh perspective on this issue.

Up until 2 days ago, I had no issues with running either `npx react-native run-ios` from my project root folder or building it in Xcode. The issue I’m facing now is when I run the build from the command line, it’s stuck on  `Building the app`  (see screenshot below).

[npx react-native run-ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbzum.png)

If I try to open  `.xcworkspace` or `.xcodeproj`  with Xcode, it immediately opens into an unresponsive state (screenshot below)

[opening .xcworkspace with Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fiz0.png).

Solutions I have tried:

1. running `react-native-clean-project` and essentially deleting `node_modules` `Pods`, etc… and reinstalling, as well as clearing cache
2. `pod reintegrate` + delete `.xcworkspace` + `pod install`
3. Installing different versions of Xcode (12.5, 13.0, 13.1)
4. Clearing Xcode cache from `username/Library`
5. Commenting out `user_flipper!()` in the `Podfile`
6. Opening a different file with Xcode (which works fine) and then opening my project’s `.xcworkspace`

Nothing seems to be working. The same build is running fine on my collaborator’s Mac with Xcode 13.

Including my `package.json` and `Podfile` below in case helpful / happy to provide any other relevant info. Thanks in advance for any potential solutions!

```
"dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.4.16",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "apollo3-cache-persist": "^0.13.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "graphql": "^16.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.4.4",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.3",
    "react-native-get-location": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-map-clustering": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.29.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.9.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions": "^5.3.23",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-knobs": "^5.3.25",
    "@storybook/react-native": "^5.3.25",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.65.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^3.6.7",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'buddyapp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  target 'buddyappTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by just recloning the repo. Hope this saves someone some time in Xcode debugging hell :)