# React Native iOS build attempt hangs, project file crashes XCode

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

These past few hours an issue has been occurring within React Native 0.68.2 on an iOS build attempt that prevents me from building my project at all, forcing me to reclone every time from the git repository to recover.

After a few edits and builds, running `npm run ios` results in it getting stuck at `Planning Build..`. When I try to manually open the XCode project file, it instantly goes into an unresponsive state.

What the Terminal outputs in its entirety when the command is ran:

```
(base) myMachine project-master % npm run ios                                            

> project@1.0.0 ios
> expo run:ios
✔ Installed pods and initialized Xcode workspace.
› Planning build (hangs here)
```

I've tried steps listed in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70105818/react-native-run-ios-stuck-on-building-and-xcode-crashes-immediately-when-openin) regarding the issue, however none of them have worked, and I constantly need to fetch the project again. Is there any way to fix this once and for all? Has been driving me crazy.

`react-native info`:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.4
    CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
    Memory: 279.42 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.15.1 - /opt/homebrew/opt/node@16/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.18 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.11.0 - /opt/homebrew/opt/node@16/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.2, iOS 15.2, macOS 12.1, tvOS 15.2, watchOS 8.3
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.2 AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683
    Xcode: 13.2.1/13C100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 17.0.1 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.68.2 => 0.68.2 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.6",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-azure-auth": "^1.8.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a weird issue with how XCode behaves with iCloud folders (Desktop, Documents, etc). Seemingly now fixed by moving my development directory to my home folder (`~/Dev/Project`).

Comment: Rats. I was hoping this would resolve my issue. Admin settings on my Mac force the Documents folder to sync with OneDrive. I moved the project out of it. No change.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled react native client and then used npx react-native run-ios

`npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`

`npx react-native run-ios`